# Pick a random word from a list of list of words, but skip empty string

Tags: python, list, random, nan

**Context**

An empty list:

`my_list = []`

I also have a list of lists of strings:

words_list = `[['this', '', 'is'], ['a', 'list', ''], ['of', 'lists']]`

But note that there are some elements in the lists that are null.

**Ideal output**

I want to randomly choose a non null element from each list in `words_list` and append that to `my_list` as an element.

e.g.

```
>> my_list 
['this', 'list', 'of']
```

**What I currently have**

```
for i in words_list:
    my_list.append(random.choice(words))
```

**My issue**

but it throws this error:

```
  File "random_word_match.py", line 56, in <module>
    get_random_word(lines)
  File "random_word_match.py", line 51, in get_random_word
    word_list.append(random.choice(words))
  File "/Users/nathancahn/miniconda3/envs/linguafranca/lib/python3.7/random.py", line 261, in choice
    raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence') from None
IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence
```

**What I don't want**

I don't want to only append the first non null element
I don't want null values in `my_list`

Comment: Maybe you should set a seed to reproduce your error as it works for me since `''` is not interpreted as None. Why not drop the null elements before choosing in the first place? This one liner works for me even with actual `None`s `[np.random.choice(x) for x in l]`

Comment: It would help if you posted a [mre], I can't get the error you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to start thinking this way:

The idea is quite simple - just go through the list of words, and choose the non-empty word then passing to *choice*.

```py
>>> for word in words_list:
    wd = choice([w for w in word if w])   # if w is non-null, choice will pick it...
    print(wd)

# then just add those non-null word into your my_list --- leave as exercise.
# Like this: 
>>> for word in words_list:
    wd = choice([w for w in word if w])
    my_list.append(wd)    
  
>>> my_list
['this', 'a', 'lists']

# Later, you could even simplify this into a List Comprehension.
```

Comment: This is helpful and is maybe highlighting a piece of logic I'm missing. How would you augment this line: `wd = choice([w for w in word if w])` to include the word fitting another pattern? e.g. a regex pattern? something simple like '[a-z]' for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```py
from random import choice

words_list = [['this', '', 'is'], ['a', 'list', ''], ['of', 'lists']]

output = [choice([word for word in words if word]) for words in words_list]

print(output) # ['is', 'a', 'lists']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and see if it works for you:

```
import random
my_list = []
words_list = [['this', '', 'is'], ['a', 'list', ''], ['of', 'lists']]
for sublist in words_list:
    filtered_list = list(filter(None, sublist))
    my_list.append(random.choice(filtered_list))
print(my_list)
```

Comment: There is no `None` in the list so this filter won't actually help. Also, this can be rewritten as a single one line list comprehension.

Comment: Interesting, it worked for me.

Comment: @NelsonGon `None` for filter checks if an element is Falsy, not whether it is a `None`. See doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter

Answer (score 0):

The `random` module contains a function `choices` that's a little more flexible than `choice`.  It will take a list of weights that determine the odds of picking a particular element; if the weight is zero, it won't be selected.

```
for words in words_list:
    weights = [w != '' for w in words]
    if any(weights):
        my_list.extend(random.choices(words, weights))

>>> my_list
['is', 'list', 'of']
```